# Getting the name of document that used to launch the application bundle on OS X

Tags: python, macos

When writing an OS X Bundle application (.app), how can I get the name of the document that caused the application to be launched?

Say I've associated .abcd with MyApp, when I click on foo.abcd MyApp is launched.
How can I get the foo.abcd from inside MyApp? (Command line arguments only contain the process id).

Comment: FWIW I don't think there is a way to do it from a shell script.
If you're using a GUI toolkit there might be support for that (tk has ::tk::mac::OpenDocument command and Qt has QFileOpenEvent)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need a GUI toolkit for that, there is an example in [idlelib/macosxSupport.py](http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Lib/idlelib/macosxSupport.py?revision=HEAD&view=markup)

```
def doOpenFile(*args):
    for fn in args:
        flist.open(fn)

# The command below is a hook in aquatk that is called whenever the app
# receives a file open event. The callback can have multiple arguments,
# one for every file that should be opened.
root.createcommand("::tk::mac::OpenDocument", doOpenFile)
```

Qt also has [support](http://doc.trolltech.com/qq/qq18-macfeatures.html) for that.

Answer (score 1):

In general, these are handled through *Apple Events*. Specifically, your application will receive an *open document* event. How you would handle it depends on what type of application you are writing.

If you're writing a document-based app, this is easy: the document controller receives an `openDocumentWithContentsOfURL:display:error:` message (or `openDocumentWithContentsOfFile:display:` for pre-Tiger systems), and will [handle this accordingly](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSDocumentController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDocumentController/openDocumentWithContentsOfURL:display:error:).

For Cocoa apps that aren't document based, the application delegate will be sent an `application:openFiles:` message. If the delegate doesn't respond to that, it will try sending other messages until the delegate responds to one (`openTempFile:`, `openFiles:`, and `openFile:`, in that order).

[Here's the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ScriptableCocoaApplications/SApps_handle_AEs/SAppsHandleAEs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001239-1119823) for handling Open Apple Events in Cocoa.

For Carbon apps, I can't really remember the details (been a while since I've written Carbon code), but if I recall correctly, you would install an Apple Event handler for `kAEOpenDocuments` events with `AEInstallEventHandler()`. See [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Carbon/Reference/Apple_Event_Manager/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/AEInstallEventHandler) for more details.

Comment: Thanks!

However in my case it's just a shell script (Python), is there a way to get it from there?

Comment: I'm not sure how to handle Apple Events with Python, actually. I found this though—hope it helps: http://wiki.python.org/moin/MacPython/AppleEvents