# How to get the path to the opened file from a script inside a OS X .app bundle?

Tags: python, macos

So I have `Foo.app`, which is configured to run `Foo.app/Contents/MacOS/foo.py` when it is launched. In the app's `Info.plist` file I also have it set as the application to handle the launching of ".bar" files. When I double-click a .bar file, `Foo.app` opens as expected.

The problem is that when a file is opened in this way, I can't figure out how to get the path to the opened file in my `foo.py` script. I assumed it would be in `sys.argv[1]`, but it's not. Instead, `sys.argv[1]` contains a strange string like "-psn_0_2895682".

Does anyone know how I can get the absolute path to the opened file? I've also checked `os.environ`, but it's not there either.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/849172/getting-the-name-of-document-that-used-to-launch-the-application-bundle-on-os-x) seems like the same question to me.

Comment: Hi ma3, that does look like the same question, although it looks like it only has support for GUI toolkits, so I'm out of luck there. I'm going to give Greg's solution a shot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get your app's process ID then ask the OS for all open files using `lsof`, looking for your process's ID:

```
from string import *
from os import getpid
from subprocess import check_output, STDOUT

pid = getpid()

lsof = (check_output(['/usr/sbin/lsof', '-p', str(pid)], stderr=STDOUT)).split("\n")
for line in lsof[1:]:
    print line
```

The regular files will be of type `'REG'` in the fifth column, `[4]` if you're indexing in.

Files open within the running code can be displayed in a similar way:
    from string import *
    from os import getpid
    from subprocess import check_output, STDOUT
    import re

```
pid = getpid()

f = open('./trashme.txt', 'w')
f.write('This is a test\n')

lsof = (check_output(['/usr/sbin/lsof', '-p', str(pid)], stderr=STDOUT)).split("\n")
print lsof[0]
for line in lsof[1:]:
    if (re.search('trashme', line)): print line 

f.close
```

Which results in:

```
COMMAND  PID USER   FD   TYPE     DEVICE  SIZE/OFF    NODE NAME
python  6995 greg    3w   REG       14,2         0 2273252 /Users/greg/Desktop/trashme.txt
```

Comment: Good solution Greg, I didn't think of that. Surely, there's got to be a more straightforward way though?

Comment: Why does there have to be a more straightforward way? This is hacking! :-)

Comment: Well I do prefer clean and easy ways when they're available, but it looks like there aren't any in this case. Thanks, I'll give it a shot.

Comment: Using 'lsof' will give you a Mac OS/Linux solution, but probably won't work on Windows, if that's important. Because the various OSes have different ways of launching an app it might be impossible to find a one-size-fits-all solution.

Comment: No dice with lsof, unfortunately. It doesn't list the opened file while my script is running. Looks like I'll have to see if I can apply one of the tricks from [this previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/849172/getting-the-name-of-document-that-used-to-launch-the-application-bundle-on-os-x)

Comment: Check the additional example I added. It shows how to locate a particular file opened by the running app.

Comment: I've tried getting the script to hang, and then running lsof from a separate shell, and the file isn't anywhere in the output, unfortunately. From the answers on the previous question, it looks like OS X doesn't actually open the file, rather it sends a message to the handling application with the file information. If that is the case, the file won't show up in lsof.

Comment: The app's process ID should show up as the child of another process. That parent's ID might have the file open. You'd have to look in the process table via `ps` if Python doesn't already have a function to give you the parent process' ID.